# Proving $ \neg ( \neg \alpha \wedge \neg \neg \alpha )$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I'm training to prove this statement , but first I need to know if this statement can be proved in :

1 -  both in classical and Intuitionistic logic ( in this case i need to provide demonstration in Intuitionistic logic )

2 -  classical logic but not Intuitionistic logic ( in this case i need to provide a Kripke Counter-Models )

3 - not provable in either classic and Intuitionistic logic ( in this case i need to provide a classic Counter-Models )

My question is how to distinguish if a statement is provable in one of this cases ?

PS :  I know the Intuitionistic logic doesn't allow the elimination of double negation

> $ \neg ( \neg \alpha \wedge \neg \neg \alpha ) $

Comment: Related: [What is a constructive proof of  $\lnot\lnot(P\vee\lnot P)$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140197/what-is-a-constructive-proof-of-lnot-lnotp-vee-lnot-p)

Comment: The question is trick", because it alludes to the *intuitionistically* "forbidden" *doble negation elimination* rule; but we do not need it to see that $\lnot \alpha \land \lnot \lnot \alpha$ is a *contradiction* : thus, its negation must be valid.

Comment: You can prove it in *Natural Deduction* assuming : 1) $¬α∧¬¬α$, deriving by $\land$-eliminartion both : 2) $¬α$ and 3) $¬¬α$ , i.e. $\lnot \alpha \to \bot$; deriving 4) $\bot$ from 2) and 3) by $\to$-elimination and finally : 5) $(¬α∧¬¬α) \to \bot$, i.e.  $¬(¬α∧¬¬α)$ from 1) and 4) by $\to$-introduction. All the rules used are *intuitionistically* valid (no *RAA*, *EM* or *Double Negation*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This statement can be proved in [minimal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_logic). When you rewrite the negations as implications in the usual way, the statement is
$$
((\alpha \to \bot) \land ((\alpha \to \bot) \to \bot) \to \bot
$$
which is really of the form
$$
(X \land X \to Y) \to Y
$$
which is just a form of modus ponens. The provability of the statement has nothing to do with negation, really, apart from rewriting the negations as implications in the usual way.

Comment: @ZeRubeus As the name suggests minimal logic has fewer rules even then intuitionistic logic, and the given proof is therefore valid in _both_ deduction systems.

Answer (score 2):

For every proposition $P$, the deduction that $P\land\lnot P\to\bot$, that is, that $\lnot(P\land\lnot P)$, is simply applying modus ponens, therefore intuitionistically valid; this is because $\lnot P$ just means $P\to\bot$. Apply this for $P=\lnot\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assume $\neg\alpha \wedge \neg\neg \alpha$, derive a contradiction. Does the resulting proof requires some use of the [double negation elimation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Negation_elimination) rule?